# Динамический массив объектов со вложенными массивами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу чтоб заработал такой способ:

```
var Cell = {
    act:false,
    ind:0,
    xmin:0,
    xmax:0,
    ymin:0,
    ymax:0,
    xs:[],
    ys:[],
}
var C = Cell = [];
funcion MyFun() {
    for(var i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
       var c = Cell = {};//обнуляю после каждой итерации
       for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          c.xs.push(Math.random());
          c.ys.push(Math.random());
       }
       C.push(c);
   }
}
```

на первой строке `c.xs.push(Math.random());` выдает ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. Как можно сделать чтоб массив с объектами имел динамические массивы внутри? Этот кусок кода должен создавать массив объектов Cell с двумя динамическими массивами внутри. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: вызывая присваивание `Cell = []` вы перетерли объявленный объект, и внутри функции `Cell` уже массив, но вы опять его перетираете `Cell = {}` и он становится пустым объектом

Comment: кроме того: `Math.random` это функция - вы уверены что вам нужна именно ссылка на функцию, а не значение, которое она возвращает?

Comment: Стоит отредактировать вопрос и добавить пояснение, что должен делать предоставленный кусок кода

Comment: а зачем вы делаете `C = Cell`, и `c = Cell`?

Comment: `C = Cell` Это объявление главного объекта, а `c = Cell` объявление временного, который заносится в Массив С как новый элемент. Это прекрасно работает кроме `c.xs.push(Math.random());`

Comment: ну вообще говоря это не работает :-) во всяком случае так, как думает вы :)

Comment: А как это тогда работает, скажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном коде две однотипные ошибки

```
var C = Cell = [];

var c = Cell = {};
```

так как в яваскрипте разрешены множественные присваивания, то таким образом значение присваивается не только переменным `C` и `c`, но и переменной `Cell`.

Таким образом после первой строки этот объект будет пустым массивом, а не объектом который был объявлен ранее, а после второй - он будет уже пустым объектом, без любых свойств  `ymin`, `ymax`, `xs`, `ys` и т.д.

Поэтому. первое что надо сделать - убрать `Cell` из этих присваиваний.

Второе: так как `Cell` тут подразумевается как класс объектов, целесообразно будет переделать его из литерального объекта в конструктор

```
function Cell () {
    this.act = false;
    this.ind = 0;
    this.xmin = 0;
    this.xmax = 0;
    this.ymin = 0;
    this.ymax = 0;
    this.xs = [];
    this.ys = [];
}
```

Теперь создавать объекты можно вызовом `new Cell()`

В итоге код может выглядеть примерно так:

```js
function Cell() {
  this.act = false;
  this.ind = 0;
  this.xmin = 0;
  this.xmax = 0;
  this.ymin = 0;
  this.ymax = 0;
  this.xs = [];
  this.ys = [];
}
var Count = 3;
var C = MyFun();
function MyFun() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
    var c = new Cell(); //обнуляю после каждой итерации
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) { //заменил название i на j так как первая уже используется в цикле выше
      c.xs.push(Math.random());
      c.ys.push(Math.random());
    }
    arr.push(c);
  }
  return arr;
}

document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(C,null,2);
```

```html
<pre id="r"><pre>
```

Comment: Результат тот-же самый. Со всеми переменными все ок, (внутри объекта). а с этими, при вызове `push` та же ошибка.

Comment: @WaldeMar, добавил пример в ответ. Сравните его с тем, что делаете вы, когда у вас не работает

Comment: У меня пишет `Cell is not a function`. Сделал все как вы написали.

Comment: @WaldeMar, добавьте код который вы используете и в котором получаете ошибку в вопрос.